# magento ajax isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

My controller has this function in it:

```
public function saveLeadDaysAction(){
        echo "works";
    }
```

And in the template phtml I am trying to this:

```
jq("#prodcal_leaddays").on("blur", function(e){
        $saveurl="<?=$this->getUrl('prodcal/adminhtml_prodcaltab/saveLeadDays');?>";
        console.log('$saveurl');
        jq.post($saveurl,{'id':'test'},function(d){
            console.log(d);
        });
    });
```

The url seems to return the entire admin dashboard page instead of the expected `works` text. However if I open the url directly in the browser, it does show the expected text.

What am I doing wrong?

Oh and I have tried appending `?isAjax=true` at the end of the url, which returns:

```
{"error":true,"message":"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."}
```

**EDIT:** Just to clarify:-
the `getUrl` generates a url like `http://localhost/devmagento/index.php/prodcal/adminhtml_prodcaltab/saveLeadDays‌​/key/d3c92257c664d8d207f5a0bdeb3edebf/` in the console.
If I copy this url from the console and paste it in the browser, it works as expected and I get the `works` text.
But when used with jQuery post, it fails and redirects to dashboard.

**EDIT 2:** It seems with post data, the key is wrong, cause if I change the above to use `GET`, and put the values within the `getUrl` function, it works properly, but the problem is since this is to be done by ajax, I need to change the values dynamically using javascript.

What I did for the get thing to work is:

```
jq("#prodcal_leaddays").on("blur", function(e){
        $saveurl="<?=$this->getUrl('prodcal/adminhtml_prodcaltab/saveLeadDays',array('id'=>'test'));?>";
        console.log($saveurl);
        jq.get($saveurl,function(d){
            console.log(d);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use POST ajax requests but you must add **?isAjax=1** to the url and **form_key** to params. Example:

```
var values = {
    'form_key': "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>"
    // ...
};
$jq.post('<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("..."); ?>?isAjax=1', values);
```

Comment: You can also use `var values = {'form_key':FORM_KEY};` in most of the admin pages, because the FORM_KEY js variable is already set in the head.

Answer (score 0):

The URL generated by this code:

```
$this->getUrl('prodcal/adminhtml_prodcaltab/saveLeadDays')
```

cannot be found, so you are redirected to the dashboard. If you try it manually, you don't have the `key` variable that is automatically added by `getUrl()` function, so you get that error. That `key` is a kind of session controller, and always changes.

To get to the right controller action, you have to check your file structure. As in your `getUrl` parameter, it shoul be / app / code / local (or community) / YourName / Prodcal / controllers / Adminhtml / ProdcaltabController.php

Return your response in this way:

```
$array = array('works');    
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array));
```

Comment: The URL IS found if I copy the url from the console log and paste it manually in the browser. So the action and the controller are both in place.

Comment: 1) add a false character to the pasted url and you will be redirected to the dashboard anyway, if you have no restrictions as administrator. Your test isn't valid.
2) The URL is always found if it is valid and even if a content body cannot be found in Magento, and it is replaced by dashboard. I updated the answer to be sure you have a body for your response.

Comment: PS: I suggest you to add in your question that you copy/pasted the URL from the console log.

Comment: ok just to be sure we are on the same page, the getUrl returns a url like: `http://localhost/devmagento/index.php/prodcal/adminhtml_prodcaltab/saveLeadDays/key/d3c92257c664d8d207f5a0bdeb3edebf/`, If I paste it in the browser, it shows `[works]`, but within the jquery post call, it redirects to dashboard. I pasted your code within the controller, but nothing changes.

Comment: I suppose this is a backend functionally, as I see adminhtml in the path and you talked about dashboard. Your url doesn't show the location of the backend, usually 'admin/'. Try to add it before prodcal. This shouldn't be necessary but may work. Maybe there is a missing statement in the module configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with adding the form_key to the url directly:

```
$saveurl="<?=$this->getUrl('prodcal/adminhtml_prodcaltab/saveLeadDays');?>form_key=" + window.FORM_KEY;
```